# Sent GNT (Golem) from Bittrex to my Ethereum wallet on my Nano Ledger

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp, golem

Ive just sent some GNT (Golem)coins from Bittrex to my ledger nano s ethereum wallet address, I have just found out that nano doesn't support GNT directly, but only through myetherwallet, is it possible to somehow get them back?

Comment: Check your address in etherscan, if you have the token in your address then you have to follow nano's support indications (ie use MyEtherWallet) to send them back to an exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Yea you can check / send them through myetherwallet by selecting the "ledger" option in "send ether and tokens" page. You'll be able to send them off the address on your ledger just fine without exposing your private key

Comment: So are my coins sitting (in my ledger address, in the etherscan) secure for now or should I quickly get them sent from my ledger address and back in to my ether wallet?